# Stored procedure mapping for many-to-many association

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I have a relatively simple table of Terms, and each Term can have multiple parents and children so there is a TermAssociation table.

```
Term          TermAssociation
----          ---------------
TermID        ParentTermID
TermName      ChildTermID
...
```

When mapped in EF, this generates a Term entity with a many-to-many association with itself.  Everything's cool.

[image]

The problem is I work in an environment where all table updates must go  through stored procedures.  I can use stored procedure mapping just fine for the Term entity, but how do I map an SP to the TermAssociation table since it's modeled as an association and not an entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do this through the designer, but it is possible if you edit the XML of the edmx file directly.  Find the association set mapping:

```
<AssociationSetMapping Name="TermAssociation" TypeName="TCPDataDictionaryModel.TermAssociation" StoreEntitySet="TermAssociation">
  <EndProperty Name="Term">
    <ScalarProperty Name="TermId" ColumnName="ParentTermId" />
  </EndProperty>
  <EndProperty Name="Term1">
    <ScalarProperty Name="TermId" ColumnName="ChildTermId" />
  </EndProperty>
</AssociationSetMapping>
```

Then add a `ModificationFunctionMapping` inside the `AssociationSetMapping`.  `InsertAssociation` is my insert SP and it takes `@ParentTermId` and `@ChildTermId` as parameters.

```
<ModificationFunctionMapping>
  <InsertFunction FunctionName="TCPDataDictionaryModel.Store.InsertAssociation" >
    <EndProperty Name="Term">
      <ScalarProperty Name="TermId" ParameterName="ParentTermId" />
    </EndProperty>
    <EndProperty Name="Term1">
      <ScalarProperty Name="TermId" ParameterName="ChildTermId" />
    </EndProperty>
  </InsertFunction>
</ModificationFunctionMapping>
```